# What is the difference between 'data' and '(data)' in typescript's subscribe method?

Tags: typescript, angular7

As title says. What is the difference between:

```
public addNewProduct() {
  if (this.f.valid) {
    this.product.count = 1;
    this.productService.saveProduct(this.product).subscribe((data) => console.log('product added or updated'));
  }
  this.router.navigate(['admin-panel/products']);
}
```

and:

```
public addNewProduct() {
  if (this.f.valid) {
    this.product.count = 1;
    this.productService.saveProduct(this.product).subscribe(data => console.log('product added or updated'));
  }
  this.router.navigate(['admin-panel/products']);
}
```

When I use first approach the template's view is updated correctly after redirecting to admin-panel/products. When I use second approach manual page refresh is needed to display updated view with added item.

Why those brackets make difference? Please, enlight me!

Comment: There's no difference; [parentheses around the parameter in a one-argument arrow function are optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Basic_syntax).  My guess is that something else is going on here.  Please consider trying to develop a [mcve] that can be used to demonstrate your issue in a standalone IDE, as described in the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(data) => {}` is essentially the same here as `data => {}`.
You can lose the parentheses if you only have one value in your tuple.
It would be different if the subscribe callback supplies a tuple with two values. Then you need the parentheses. `(data, moreData) => {}`.

Your problem is not in this code.
You have a timing issue, because depending on the execution time of `saveProduct()`, the call to `this.router.navigate(['admin-panel/products']);` could be executed too early. Change your code so the navigate is executed when your subscribtion callback is executed.

```
public addNewProduct() {
  if (this.f.valid) {
    this.product.count = 1;
    this.productService.saveProduct(this.product).subscribe(data => { 
      console.log('product added or updated'));
      // Place it here.
      this.router.navigate(['admin-panel/products']);
    });
    // Because here is too early.
  }
  else {
    // And here if your condition is not met, if this seems logical to you.
    this.router.navigate(['admin-panel/products']);
  }
}
```

A test to prove execution timing problems:

```
public test() {
  of('').pipe(delay(1000)).subscribe(() => console.log(1));
  console.log(2);
}

Output:
2
1
```